# How can I replace an item in a row with another item from diffrent dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, replace

I have a df where in every row I have words in lists. I have another df where in one column I have some of the words and a category in second column. I would like to replace words in first df with category from another df and clean other words in first df.

[image]

[image]

Here's what is not working:

```
{for word in tweets_tab_merged2['cleaned_tweet']:
    if word in tuple(NAWL_merged_NA['word']):
        words = [word.replace(NAWL_merged_NA['word'], NAWL_merged_NA['category']) for w in words]}
```

Comment: You can clarify your desired result by showing how it should look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this. One is by using exploding the list, merging the category column in the individual words, and reaggregating the lists. Looking at the images you provided, your first table is `tweets_tab_merged2` and you second table with categories is `NAWL_merged_NA`. Your code might look something like this:

```
ttm2_expl = tweets_tab_merged2.explode("cleaned_tweet")
ttm2_expl = ttm2_expl.reset_index()
ttm2_expl = ttm2_expl.merge(NAWL_merged_NA, how="left", left_on="cleaned_tweet", right_on="word")
ttm2_expl.drop(columns=["word"], inplace=True)
tweets_tab_merged2 = ttm2_expl.group_by(by="index").aggregate(lambda group: [word for word in group if word is not None])
tweets_tab_merged2.drop(columns=['index'], inplace=True)
```

With sample data, it seems to work:

```
tweets_tab_merged2 = pd.DataFrame([{"cleaned_tweet":['a','b','c']},{"cleaned_tweet":['c']},{"cleaned_tweet":['a','b']}])
NAWL_merged_NA = pd.DataFrame([{'word':'a', 'category':'x'},{'word':'b', 'category':'y'},{'word':'c', 'category':'z'}])

...
tweets_tab_merged2
              category
cleaned_tweet
a               [x, x]
b               [y, y]
c               [z, z]
```